# case sensitivity when running OS X app from terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, case-sensitive

i've noticed that when i run application from the terminal stating its direct path, it depends on case sensitivity. i've found out that when MacOS is written in lower case, it fails to run due to lack plist file, as can bee seen below :

```
[13:37 zzz ~/ ] /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/macos/notes    
2015-07-23 13:37:34.924 notes[1205:12990] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting
```

whereas the correct case manage to run the application.

```
[13:37 zzz ~/ ]$ /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/notes
```

can you tell me what is the reason for this behavior ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is a consequence of the formatting of the hard drive you're using.

If your hard drive (or SSD) had "case-sensitive" formatting, that's why you need to be explicit about `MacOS` instead of `macos`.

If you had formatted your hard drive for simply "Journaled", then you could get away with using all caps.

[More information can be found here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not).

Comment: ok, i saw in your links, that there's an option to cancel case-sensitivity without reformatting, using the following line :  echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc

Comment: Assuming you're using `tcsh` (which I think is the default shell with MacOS), you could do the `set complete=igncase` environment variable thing and when I just tried it, it auto completes regardless of case sensitivity.  [More info found here](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html).  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to permanently set it via your `.tcshrc` file. :-)